# Parse string to date in android and compare

Tags: android

I have a problem. I have two strings. Every element has date format. I can use `Date.parse(string)` to parse string to date. Now I have a problem how can I compare this two strings, because I want to check which date is higher. If I have one string `6-05-2012` and second `12-05-2012` I want to check which date is higher(in this case will be `12-05-2012`). How I can do that? Maybe is other way, without parsing to date?

Comment: check this out please, http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compare-dates-in-java/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this.

You can use the `after` and `before` method also.

Check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html).

```
public void compareDate() {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date1 = sdf.parse("2009-12-31");
        Date date2 = sdf.parse("2010-01-31");

        if(date1.compareTo(date2)>0){
            Log.v("app","Date1 is after Date2");
        }else if(date1.compareTo(date2)<0){
            Log.v("app","Date1 is before Date2");
        }else if(date1.compareTo(date2)==0){
            Log.v("app","Date1 is equal to Date2");
        }
    } catch(Exception e) { }
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter why you downvote it. You should not do this thing without letting to mistake..

Comment: I agree with @TGMCians you should give the explanation why you down voted. If it is for a valid reason I second otherwise not.

Answer (score 1):

```
private Date compareDates(final String dateString)
{

    SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");  
    Date date = null;
    try {  
        format.parse(dateString);  
    } catch (Exception e) {  
        Log.d(getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());           
    }
    return date;
}
```

Now you can compare between two dates. Hope this will help for more reference to `SimpleDateFormat` please check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Noe you can use `date.getTime()` to compare your dates.

Answer (score 1):

Try this --

```
String dtStart = "2010-10-15T09:27:37Z";  
SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");  
try {  
    Date date = format.parse(dtStart);  
    System.out.println(date);  
} catch (ParseException e) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

OR

```
public static long compareTo( java.util.Date date1, java.util.Date date2 )  
{  
//returns negative value if date1 is before date2  
//returns 0 if dates are even  
//returns positive value if date1 is after date2  
  return date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();  
} 

String strDate1 = "10-JAN-1920";  
String strDate2 = "10-APR-1950";  

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd-MMM-yyyy" );  
java.util.Date d1 = sdf.parse( strDate1 );  
java.util.Date d2 = sdf.parse( strDate2 );  

System.out.println( "1. " + sdf.format( d1 ).toUpperCase() );  
System.out.println( "2. " + sdf.format( d2 ).toUpperCase() );  

if ( compareTo( d1, d2 ) < 0 )  
{  
   System.out.println( "d1 is before d2" );  
}  
else if ( compareTo( d1, d2 ) > 0 )   
{  
   System.out.println( "d1 is after d2" );  
}  
else  
{  
   System.out.println( "d1 is equal to d2" );  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I this another best way to compare dates it to use date class itself

```
 void dateComparator() throws ParseException {
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
      Date date1 = sdf.parse("2009-12-31");
      Date date2 = sdf.parse("2010-01-31");

      if (date1.before(date2)) {
         System.out.println("Date1 is before Date2");
      } else if (date1.after(date2)) {
         System.out.println("Date1 is after Date2");
      } else if (date1.equals(date2)) {
         System.out.println("Date1 is equal to Date2");
      } else {
         System.out.println("How to get here?");
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You better off using Joda time. See http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/index.html for more information. The standard API is somehow limited and complicated and forces you to reinvent already made methods made in Joda time